# Team Foundation server project template

Tags: tfs

When we create a project in TFS, we always follow these steps:
1) Create new team project
2) Create workspace, assocate to source control folder and local folder
3) Create three folders under team project (Main, Dev, Release)
4) Check in source to Main
5) Convert Main to branch
6) Create Dev/Dev and Release/Release branches from Main branch

These 6 steps are pretty much stock for every project we build, but it is possible for developers to get it wrong or stray from this design.  Is there something available for TFS that we can use to automate this process?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new team project with the "tfpt createteamproject" (from the power tools). You can also execute all your tasks from the command line to (use the tf and the tfpt commands).

In your case, creating a batch file that executes all these commands could be your solution