# automating a directory structure on new Team Project creation

Tags: tfs

Consider the process when creating a new Team Project.

There's a convention to be followed: Team Projects need to have a directory structure like this:

```
MyTeamProject
             -Dev
                 -Dev
             -Main
                 -Docs
                 -Source
             -Release
```

How can this directory structure/layout be **automated**, or otherwise taken out of the initial developer's hands? Are there any built in configuration spots in TFS 2010 to help achieve this?

There is a mix of training and convention involved here outside of TFS, but the idea is to set all the developers up for success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a batch file to create and checkin all these directories.

As stated in [Team Foundation server project template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982321/team-foundation-server-project-template) you can create a batch file that first creates a team project and then add all the folders to version control

Comment: We had to create several team projects that had the same basic structure and did just that.  Good suggestion.